# C++ GMP equivalent of pow (a,b) using mpz_class

Tags: c++, gmp, pow

I'm trying to calculate `a` to the power of `b` where `a` and `b` are of `mpz_class` type. There aren't enough samples and explanations on the GMP manual. Here is my take with the comments:

```
#include <gmpxx.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    mpz_class r;
    mpz_class a = 2;
    mpz_class b = 3;

    mpz_ui_pow_ui (r.get_mpz_t(), 2, 3);// Works
    // mpz_ui_pow_ui (r.get_mpz_t(), a.get_mpz_t(), b.get_mpz_t());
    /* Doesn't work. Gives
 invalid conversion from 'mpz_ptr' {aka '__mpz_struct*'} to 'long unsigned int' [-fpermissive] error. In the the official documentation, there a bunch of similar pow functions such as
mpz_powm(mpz_t rop , const mpz_t base , const mpz_t exp , const mpz_t mod) without any samples.
    */
    std::cout << r << '\n';
}
```

How to do it?

I've tried:

```
mpz_pow_ui (r.get_mpz_t(), a.get_mpz_t(), b.get_mpz_t());
```

and it gave the same error.

Because b is 3 ie a very small number, I've tried:

```
mpz_pow_ui (r.get_mpz_t(), a.get_mpz_t(), b.mpz_get_ui());
```

and it gave `no member named __gmpz_get_ui` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no function in GMP to raise one unbounded integer to the power of another. presumably because any such calculation would overflow with numbers that are too big to fit into fixed size integers.

The closest to what you want is `mpz_pow_ui`, which raises a unbounded integer to the power of a fixed size integer.

Comment: there is with modulo: https://machinecognitis.github.io/Math.Gmp.Native/html/93210ab6-2523-3130-044a-80bcf43c181d.htm. If the values are not too big, a huge mod can get the correct result (without mod), or do I miss something?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Point I'm making is that given x ^ y and excluding the special cases of x == 0 or |x| == 1 then if y is too large to fit into a ui the result is guaranteed to overflow. So there is not much point in supplying the `mpz_pow` function that the OP seems to want. I assuming they're not interested modulo arithemetic.

Comment: Alright.  Can I then calculate `2`  to the power of  `3` using Big Numbers, i.e. with some other library other than GMP or using some trick? Or do I have to write a new library just to do it?

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen You can calculate it with `mpz_pow_ui` (or `mpz_ui_pow_ui` as you have above). I'm not seeing the problem you are seeing I'm afraid.

Comment: @john I've tried it. See the OP edited. It didn't work.

Comment: @Lars: As the answer says, the exponent (third argument) cannot be an `mpz_class` it has to be an ordinary integer.  The function signature is `mpz_pow_ui (mpz_t rop, const mpz_t base, unsigned long int exp)`

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen Well obviously it doesn't because the parameter types are wrong. You need to **convert** your mpz_class variable to an integer variable, after checking that the conversion would not overflow.

Comment: @LarsMalmsteen Use `mpz_cmp_ui` to see if your `b` variables value is small enough (whatever that means for you) and if it is use `mpz_get_ui` to convert `b` to an ordinary integer variable. Then use the converted variable in `mpz_pow_ui`.

Comment: @john I've tried the last suggestion. It didn't work.

Comment: Read the doc more carefully, it is `b.get_ui()` (after checking that `b.fits_ulong_p()`), or `mpz_get_ui(b.get_mpz_t())`.